# Set Github Action deployment job target environment conditionally

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I'm creating a `deploy.yml` for my Github Action job. One very first section about the job definition is to define some information on the environment:

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production
```

While this works perfect for production environment, it can be very scary for dev & testing deployment. My question is really how to set the value for `environment` dynamically based on the target branch? For example, pushing into `dev` branch will set `environment: dev` and `test` branch will set `environment: test`.

I have tried `environment: $GITHUB_REF_NAME` but it just simply print it as a plain string when sending alerts to slack.
[image]

Appreciate if anyone could advise.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "very scary"? Please also show based on what you want to set this value.

Comment: Hi @rethab, thanks for the comments. I have explained a bit further in the code. I was basically trying to set the environment value based on target branch so it can display proper target environment in the deployment log. Currently it's always `productions`. Seeing the message `You are deploying into production` in dev or testing stage is scary as developers may think it's an accidental deployment to production.